# Why is a different convention used for the $Rz$ implementation on IBM Q?

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

A $z$ rotation gate is defined as
$$
Rz(\theta)=\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}Z}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}
\end{pmatrix},
$$

however, when one uses $Rz$ gate on IBM Q, the results are these (tested in Visualization of state vector):

- $Rz(\theta)|0\rangle = |0\rangle$
- $Rz(\theta)|1\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}|1\rangle$

This means that a matrix representation of such gate is

$$
Rz^{\text{IBM}}(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So, it seems that $Rz(\theta)$ is on IBM Q implemented with $U1(\theta)$ gate.

Since gates $Rz(\theta)$ and $Rz(\theta)^\text{IBM}$ differs only by global phase $\theta/2$ ($Rz^\text{IBM} = \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}Rz(\theta))$, this difference can be neglected. However, in case of controlled version of $z$ rotation the global phase matters.

Controlled version of $Rz$ is described by matrix

$$
CRz(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

On IBM Q, controlled version of $Rz$ behaves according to this matrix which is right.

Despite the global phase can be neglected in case of single qubit gates, one would expect that relation between a single qubit gate $U$ and its contolled version, i.e.

$$
CU=
\begin{pmatrix}
I & O \\
O & U
\end{pmatrix},
$$

will be preserved. In some cases the convention used by IBM for $Rz$ can be confusing (discussed for example [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/are-mathrmcrz-with-angle-pi-and-mathrmcz-equal-on-the-ibm-quantum-e/10026#10026)).

So far, I have counted with this fact but I am curious: **Why does IBM use its own convention and does not follow definitions used in quantum physics?**

*(I would appreciate if somebody from IBM Q development team could give an insight to this).*

Comment: It might have something to do with how the IBM Q experience physically implements the $R_{z}$ gate, which is actually not at all, but via frame changes of the $X$ and $Y$ operation: they perform rotations along any axis in the $X-Y$ plane, and keep track through software what the actual $X-$ and $Y-$axis are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'm not from IBM Q development team, but here is how I understand the problem:**

[Qiskit's definition of $R_z$](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/f72f5cd5fcdc83b323685b5e4fb1f0545fc67ebd/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/rz.py#L40-L44) gate coincides with the conventional definition used, for example, in M. Nielsen and I. Chuang's textbook (page 174):

$$R_z(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-i \theta/2}  &0 \\ 0&e^{i \theta/2} \end{pmatrix}$$

The "problem" is not in the **definitions**, the "problem" is in the **implementations**.

Although Qiskit's implementation of `rz` gate coincides with the `u1` gate, the implementations of `crz` and `cu1` are different and coincide with the conventional definitions. Nevertheless, I think this still can cause some problems. For example, after creating a circuit with `rz` gate in it, one may want to create a controlled version of the circuit with Qiskit's `get_controlled_circuit` method that will not give `crz` gate, but `cu1`, as a result, there will be some logical errors.

Here are the codes and corresponding circuits in `qasm` format for all mentioned 4 gates

**$R_z$ gate:**

```
circuit_rz = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit_rz.rz(1.4, 0)
circuit_rz = transpile(circuit_rz, basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'], optimization_level=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u1(1.4) q[0];
```

**$cR_z$ gate:**

```
circuit_crz = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit_crz.crz(1.4, 0, 1)
circuit_crz = transpile(circuit_crz, basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'], optimization_level=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u1(0.7) q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];
u1(-0.7) q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];
```

**$u1$ gate:**

```
circuit_u1 = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit_u1.u1(1.4, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u1(1.4) q[0];
```

**$cu1$ gate:**

```
circuit_cu1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit_cu1.cu1(1.4, 0, 1)
circuit_cu1 = transpile(circuit_cu1, basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'], optimization_level=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u1(0.7) q[0];
cx q[0],q[1];
u1(-0.7) q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];
u1(0.7) q[1];
```