# Qiskit Controlled S and Controlled T Gates

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit

I was implementing controlled S and T gates in qiskit and was wondering if there is any difference between using the [`cu1`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CU1Gate.html) and [`crz`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CRZGate.html) gates for this purpose. Qiskit doesn't seem to include explicit versions of these two gates.

```
circuit = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2)
# a)
circuit.crz(theta=math.pi/2, control_qubit=0, target_qubit=1)
# b)
circuit.cu1(theta=math.pi/2, control_qubit=0, target_qubit=1)
```

In terms of the unitary the `cu1` gate seems closer to what one would want, I would assume. Are there any other consequences I should be aware of?

Comment: cu1 will be deprecated in favor of [cp](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CPhaseGate.html#qiskit.circuit.library.CPhaseGate), but the answer still holds. Using `cp` will be more concise, but luciano's answer using Gate().control renders more nicely in diagrams (as controlled S not as controlled P (pi/2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qiskit you can get the controlled version of any gate with the method `control`.
For S and T, here is the example:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates import SGate, TGate

csgate = SGate().control(1) # the parameter is the amount of control points you want
ctgate = TGate().control(1)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.append(csgate, [0, 1])
circuit.append(ctgate, [0, 1])
print(circuit)
```

```
q_0: ──■────■──
     ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ S ├┤ T ├
     └───┘└───┘
```

If you want to compare these gates with `cu1` or `crz`, you can use the `Operator` class:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates import CRZGate, CU1Gate
from math import pi

from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
print(Operator(CU1Gate(pi/2)) == Operator(csgate))
print(Operator(CRZGate(pi/4)) == Operator(ctgate))
```

```
True
False
```

Comment: edited to include that comment.

Answer (score 0):

`cu1` and `crz` are different gates and the difference is explained in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13414/9459). One can express $cS$ and $cT$ gates with `cu1` gate, but it is impossible to express them with `crz` gate.

$$
cS = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&i \\
\end{pmatrix} =
cu1(\pi/2)
\qquad
cT = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i \pi/4} \\
\end{pmatrix} =
cu1(\pi/4)
$$

while

$$
cRz(\alpha) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&e^{-i \alpha/2}&0 \\
0&0&0&e^{i \alpha/2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and there is no way to choose such $\alpha$ for $cRz(\alpha)$ to be equal to $cS$ or $cT$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I hastily assumed that I could get rid of the rotation on |0> as a global phase.

Comment: @midor, you are welcome :)