# Inverse Quantum Fourier Transformation

Tags: qiskit, quantum-fourier-transform

I have the exercise to implement the Inverse QFT with Qiskit for any number of qubits without the swapping part. I tried to implement something like this for any $n$.
[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform]

Now I got this code but it doesn't work and I'm kinda lost because I do not know if it's a mistake of the controlled Z-rotation (which we have to do using only Single Qubit Gates and CNOT) or if I misunderstood the inverse Fourier transformation and have to do something else.

```
    #Implementation of the inverse QFT

def inverse_QFT(n):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n)

    pi = np.pi
    # do the rotations with for loops on the quantumregister q = (q[n-1],...,q[1],q[0])
    for j in range(n-1,-1,-1):
         #Hadamard on the jth qubit
         qc.h(j)
         for k in range(j-1,-1,-1):
             # The Controlled Z Rotations by theta

            theta = 2*pi / (2**(j-k))
            qc.cx(j,k)
            qc.rz(-theta, j)
            qc.cx(j,k)
            qc.rz(theta, j)
return qc
```

I wanted to add, that the code does work (so I get an output) but does not give me the right answer.

**Edit:** I changed the exponent from $k$ to $j-k$. But it still does not work.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of the code. Instead, please type the code directly into the question to allow access to it for search machines.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out, that the Rz gate didn't do what I thought it did. I found another a way to represent the controlled phase gate with single qubit gates and CNOT over this Link https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213002/in-quantum-fourier-transform-why-can-any-controlled-r-k-gate-be-formed-by-t/213168#213168
So I changed the code to the following

```
        for j in range(n-1,-1,-1):
             #Hadamard on the jth qubit
             qc.h(j)
             p = 0
             for k in range(j):
                 p += 1
                 # controlled phase gate
                 #qc.cp(-pi/(2**(p)),j-k-1,j)
                 #single qubit and CNOT
                 theta = (2*pi/2**(p))           
                 qc.p(2*theta, j-k-1)
                 qc.p(2*theta, j)
                 qc.cx(j-k-1,j)
                 qc.p(-2*theta, j)
                 qc.cx(j-k-1,j)
       for k in range (int(n/2)):
           qc.swap(k, n-1-k)
        
       return qc
```

This works perfectly fine

Comment: Related a maybe helpful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/why-is-a-different-convention-used-for-the-rz-implementation-on-ibm-q